# I need to extract data from "Request" tab

Tags: jmeter

My Request Tab (In "View Result Tree" listener)

```
GET https://example.com/index.html

GET data:


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Authorization: Basic ZGVtb2FhY29lQGdtYWlsLmNvbTpVbmlzeXMqMTIz
```

I need value of "Authorization", How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as Post Processor of request to get Authorization Header using: Field to check `Request Headers` and with Regular expression to get value:

```
Authorization: (.*)
```

Use Template `$1$` and Match No. `1` to get the first value.